# Handlebars: Is there a way to output a full object that is part of an array (with "each")?

Tags: arrays, object, this, each, handlebars.js

So this is my Data-Set I want to pass Handlebars:

```js
Handlebars.templates.test({Events: Events, foo1: foo1, foo2: foo2 });
```

The focus will be on "Events: Events" :

```html
Events = [
  {bla1: "John W", bla2: "14:00"}, //this is one Event
  {bla1: "Jason K", bla2: "18:00"} //and this is one Event
]
```

And this is test.handlebars

```html
{{#each Events}}
 <div data-event="{{this}}">  <--- Here i want to insert the whole Object (Event)

  <div>{{this.bla1}}</div>
  <div>{{this.bla2}}</div>
 </div>

{{/each}}
```

How can I pass the whole Event as an Object to data-event?
I tried it with {{this}} (like above) but it failed for me.

Answer (score 0):

ok finally I found a solution:

```js
var Events[i].Event_string = JSON.stringify(Events[i]);

Events = [
  {bla1: "John W", bla2: "14:00", Event_string: Event_string},
...
```

```html
<div data-event="{{this.Event_string}}">
```